# Angular Upload To Firebase, Source Code Not Uploaded

Tags: angular, firebase-hosting

I tried deploying my angular to firebase for the first time and i followed the steps properly and i also successfully created a custom url but when i use **firebase deploy** every thing goes successfully but if i go to the link and check, i find out that the source files were not uploaded
and i get this

[image: page display]

I installed firebase tools,
Also used firebase init,
followed the steps and did it right then i also did firebase deploy

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this with an app I deployed two weeks ago. There seems to be some lag recently, it corrected itself in a few hours.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this is showing up because your app is missing a valid entry point as you might not have an `index.html` in the root directory of your folder.

if you want to use a custom path or use a wildcard in case you are building a SPA you can route all the paths to your entry point by editing your `firebase.json` file and setting the rewrites array.

you can learn more about rewrites in the firebase docs: [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites)